# Daily vote supply getting shut off prematurely

Tags: bug, voting

Users are allowed to up/downvote up to 40 posts per day (with the supply refilling at 0000 UTC).  However, there seems to be a bug regarding this; for each of the past several days, I've been getting the "Daily vote limit reached; vote again in *[xxx]* hours." message after only 37 or 38 votes, which is kinda frustrating when it means I'm left with a couple good questions and/or answers that I have to wait another day before I can upvote.  Why is the votes-used-today limit triggering prematurely?

Answer (score 7):

This is because the daily vote limit is actually *30*, not 40, but you get a maximum of 10 bonus votes, one for each *question* you vote before you see the "*N* votes left" warning. This is to encourage more voting on questions.

For more details, see the question [Cannot vote on question although 40 votes limit not reached](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/90726/295232) on Meta Stack Exchange.